# How to dynamically pass env variable to supervisorctl?

Tags: supervisord

I mean not in the `supervisord.conf` file, but instead - when you start/restart some process via `supervisorctl restart procname`. I've tried `ENVTEST=something supervisorctl start env-test` but it didn't work.

Here are some pieces of what I have:

supervisord.conf:

```
[program:env-test]
command=python env_test.py
stdout_logfile=logs/env_test.log
autostart=false
```

env_test.py:

```
import os

print('envtest:', os.environ.get('ENVTEST'))
```

command I've tried: `ENVTEST=something supervisorctl start env-test`

Solution that comes to my mind is to make my programs use some env-file and change it before restarting.

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far I went with:

`pip install python-dotenv`

env_test.py:

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

print('envtest:', os.environ.get('ENVTEST'))
```

.env file:

```
ENVTEST=something
```

and start it as usual: `supervisorctl start env-test`

This way the variable is available to the python code.